# Is their a way to click on a <a> tag without having to physically click it?

Tags: javascript

If I see a link referencing to a website or action, is there a way I can make an external program that can click on that  tag without physically having to take my mouse and click on the link? I know their are probably programs that can take your mouse pointer and move the pointer and possibly make them click, but I am looking for something that will click a link without having to worry about your mouse moving. Thank You

Comment: In javascript you can't do it.

Comment: Have you ever seen Selenium?

Comment: alex's comment should be the answer to this question - selenium is amazing.

Comment: Selenium is only answer, Alex should make his comment the answer as said before.

Answer (score 7):

in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$('a.theOne').click();
```

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a server-side testing tool the simulates clicks on the client-side for testing purposes.

Also, if jQuery does it then it is possible with regular javascript, but I'm not sure how. A look through [the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js) should reveal the secret.

According to [this article](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/05/simulate-a-button-click-via-javascript/) you simply need to call:

```
document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the link href and go to it via `window.location.assign()`